# jQuery: slideDown jumpy after slideUp — height problem?

Tags: jquery

This is a common problem, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995445/jquery-box-height-problem-using-slideup-down) and [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/), however I can't find a solution to it.

I have a container (#a) that I load external files into. First the current content is hidden with a slideUp function, then the new content is loaded and finally the container appears with a slideDown. However the animation is jumpy because when it slideDown it calculates the height of the previous content. How can I make it calculate the height of the new content instead?

You can see [the problem in action here](http://www.productsofmagnus.com/x/load/) (click one of the three first links in the left column) and here is the jQuery:

```
$('.kolonne a').click(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#a').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).load(url); 
    }); 

    $('#a').slideDown();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that you need to make the slideDown only after the content is loaded, try a callback like this:

```
$('.kolonne a').click(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#a').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).load(url, function() {
           //done
           $('#a').slideDown();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks, maestro! :-)